# Choosing a similarity metric for user-scores of television shows

Tags: similarity, cosine-similarity

I have a database of user ratings of various television shows on a 1-10 scale. I've been trying to find a good way of determining how similar two user score-lists are two one another for shared shows.

It feels like the most obvious way to do this is just to take the absolute value of the difference. And then sum/average that for all shared shows. But I was reading this does not take into account how users will rate things on different scales. I saw some people saying cosine similarity is better for this sort of thing. Unfortunately, I've run into a lot of cases where that metric doesn't really make sense.

Example:

```
overall average of user1 = 8.1

overall average of user2 = 5.8
```

scores for shared shows only:

```
S1 = [8,8,10,10,10,10,6,8,10,5,6,10]

S2 = [5,6,7,8,9,9,4,5,9,1,2,8]
```

Obviously, these two people rated the shows they watched pretty differently. When I use the average difference it says they are not very similar (2.3 where 0 is the same). When I use something like the cosine similarity it says they are extremely similar (0.97 where 1 is the same).

Is there a metric that would be better suited for this kind of thing? My ultimate goal is to recommend users shows from other users that have similar tastes to them.

Comment: May be follow way: `average of user1 = 8.1'. So each rating various difference: `[-0.1, -0.1, +1.9, +1.9...]`. Did can u use this data?

Comment: If you mean did I try centering the data, yeah I did. This gave better results. Do you think this is the best way to do this sort of thing though? I'm kinda flying by the seat of my pants.